# How can I get advantage on a lock-pick check?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, advantage-and-disadvantage

What can my player do to get advantage with picking a lock (or all locks) without relying on another PC's help action?  Is there an item that grants this, or a scenario in which the DM should impose advantage?

Comment: Is the player a spellcaster?  Or are they 100% rogue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The easiest way is a wonderous item that grants the Cat's Grace version of the Enhance Ability Spell X times per day.

You could go with  a wand, potion, or a ring of spell storing, but they still rely on a spellcaster at some point.  I  am assuming the player in question is not spellcaster.  Still, it is much less of a drain on their fellow spellcaster's resources.

### Other Options

A magnifying glass gives advantage to all checks when manipulating something small.  Perhaps, if the DM is so inclined, a jeweler's loop may help the lock picker.

Perhaps they inherit an exceptionally fine, non-magical, set of lock picks.  Or maybe they are magical.  Such a thing would surely be pursued by theives, though!

There is the option of spending inspiration, but I hope they don't have too many locks to get through.

**As always, the DM get to choose what grants advantage.  It can't hurt to start a dialog.**

Comment: DM reasons I can think of to ad-hoc give advantage on a lock. Previous knowledge of the particular lock (seen the key, unlocked many of this type before) or perhaps some other insight into a weakness of the locking mechanism (Player investigates lock first "a gentle twist of the lock's barrel reveals that there is a greater degree of movement than there should be. It has either been installed with little care or endured mistreatment; either way, this lock would be susceptible to a good, ol' fashion riggling")

Comment: We had a dwarven lockpicker who was a former locksmith, he got a +2  bonus on any of the locks he made (18 or better on a d20 to determine) for certain ones(nat 20) he even had a skeleton key and got a +8.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a DM awarded Inspiration point, that acts as having advantage for one roll.  If your DM does not award inspiration, I suggest you have a talk with the DM concerning that feature.  (DMG 239-241).

There is an answer covering [negotiating with your DM for Inspiration here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/67164/22566).

Some ideas on suggesting where advantage is appropriate (credit to @Luke)

1. Previous knowledge of the particular lock (seen the key, unlocked
   many of this type before)
2. Situational insight into a weakness of the locking mechanism (Player
   investigates lock first "a gentle twist of the lock's barrel reveals
   that there is a greater degree of movement than there should be
3. been installed with little care or endured mistreatment; either way,
   this lock would be susceptible to a good, ol' fashion riggling"

Granted, some of the above may be folded into the DC that the DM assigns to a given lock in the first place, but it never hurts to ask/investigate.   Discuss with your DM.

Answer (score 1):

### Do anything that would, in older D&D editions, provide a positive modifier to the check

5e uses advantage in lieu of modifiers, so achieving advantage on such a task should be fairly trivial in the absence of time pressure.  For example, you could:

- research the locksmithing methods of the creator of the lock for hints about weaknesses in the lock's construction.
- approach the lock midmorning, after a full night's sleep, breakfast, and a morning of preparatory exercises.
- use drugs to optimize your mental state
- ask an NPC to use the help action
- entreat the God of Thieves for aid on the task, perhaps with a small sacrifice at a shrine or somesuch
- Use a wedge to maintain torsion wrench pressure without active involvement, so you can pick the lock tumbler by tumbler over a matter of days rather than hours.
- Solicit advice from persons of greater skill at an appropriate venue
- Use thieves' tools manufactured by the same culture group as the security measures.